# PHP: Can't write to file on Bitnami Debian LAMP

Tags: php, debian, lamp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have no problems with the code on my local Windows XAMPP installation and on a shared hosting server, but on the AWS LightSail Debian LAMP installation the code stops working without an error.

I'm creating a temp file and then filling it with CSV data.

```
$file = fopen($filename, 'w+') or die("Unable to create file!");
// Write header line
$header = "email_id, email_address, email_subject, email_timestamp, email_event" . PHP_EOL;
fwrite($file, $header) or die("Could not write headers to file");
```

There is a loop that writes the CSV data...

```
$cRow = $email_id . ', "' . $email_address . '", "' . $email_subject . '", ' . $email_timestamp . ', "' . $email_event . '"' . PHP_EOL;
fwrite($file, $cRow) or die("Could not write headers to file");
```

The file gets created with user *daemon* while the rest of the PHP files are owned by *www-data*

[image]

I've tried changing user permission and groups etc but nothing works. The content does not get written and there is no "Could not write headers to file" error. The size of the file stays 0.

Comment: Do you get any error when running the PHP code using the command line? Is there any error in the Apache's log (`/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log`) related to that?

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The Apache and PHP-FPM processes in the Bitnami solutions run using the daemon user and group. That's why the files are created using the daemon user and group. Please ensure that user and group have read and write permissions in the folder.

```
sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /path/to/your/app/folder
sudo chmod g+w /path/to/your/app/folder
```

Comment: I use "sudo chown -R daemon:daemon ~/htdocs/admin"  No change. Still empty files...

Comment: At least in my case, the proper setup was sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /path/to/your/folder